# SPIKE fuzzer gives LD_LIBRARY_PATH issue on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to configure SPIKE file fuzzer on Ubuntu machine. It gives `Now you need to set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the path to libdisasm.so and the path to libdlrpc.so`.

I did set LD_LIBRARY_PATH using export. But it is still showing up the same error again. Seems LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not working for SPIKE. How do I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

With your LD_LIBRARY_PATH set run ldd on the fuzzer executable (I'm assuming it's an executable). It should show you the libraries that are used and potentially missing. Keeping fixing your path until all the dependencies are met.

```
[user@host jobs]$ ldd `which gcc`
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3e193000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa2c1f4c000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa2c1d34000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa2c197d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa2c2275000)
```

Comment: I see the error while using ./make.sh command, which is basically to build fuzzer. Executable is not yet generated. I suppose

Comment: Try adding a -x to the end of the #!/bin/bash line at the top of make.sh:  '#!/bin/bash -x' to find out what command isn't working. There's probably some executable running that running ldd on will show you the problem.